# Article Component not properly show in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

i am new to joomla i use this code for article in joomla

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

and result

```
Specialty Market
Details
Category: Uncategorised
Published on Tuesday, 22 January 2013 10:01
Written by Super User
Hits: 0
Specialty Market...
Next >
Our Markets
The Rock Brook Consulting Group provides a comprehensive range of services...
```

but i only need this

```
Our Markets
The Rock Brook Consulting Group provides a comprehensive range of services...
```

please help ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hide those thing just hide those from article manager.For doing this go to `article manager->options->disable` the option which you don't want to show in your article and save it.

For more information see this link:

[Help25:Content Article Manager Options](http://docs.joomla.org/Help25%3aContent_Article_Manager_Options)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can remove this only for specific article. When you are editing article click on "Article Options" (right panel) and change the options you are interested.
It will override the options selected by ( article manager->options->disable )